# Maximal power dissipation of the resistances in this circuit

Tags: resistors, power-dissipation

Assuming I have this circuit below with :
Ic = 200mA , β = 100 , UCE = 15 V

[image]

So with some calculations : Ib = 2mA , R1 = 4k7 Ohm , R2 = 75 Ohm

If I want to calculate the power dissipation of both URV1 and URV2 then :
$$P1 = U_{R1} . I_{b}$$
and
$$P2 = U_{R2} . I_{c}$$

But the question here was to calculate the maximal power dissipation of the resistances R1 and R2.
Does this mean that I have to check the minimum value of the amplification factor β arccording to the transistor that I have . In other words, If I want to have the maximum value of IB I would need the minimum value of β to use since the formula is  $$ I_{B} * β = I_{C} $$   Is this how should I consider it or is there another way to calculate the maximal power dissipation of both resistances .

Comment: Power dissipated in a resistor = \$I_{resistor}^2\cdot R\$. Does that help?

Comment: I know but what confused me was to calculate the maximal power dissipation . Does this mean I have to find out the maximum value of IB (I_resistor)  ?

Comment: I can't see an image of the original question so you have to figure this out yourself. There may be clues that you have dismissed or overlooked.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. Hfe=50, If=0.2A, 
Rv1=2.2 kOhm.Ibb should be 4 mA. Power dissipation is U^2/R, voltage should be taking maximum.

Comment: Yeah sorry I considered Hfe=100